# Post method gets converted to GET after redirection

Tags: karate

I have one POST call related to search.It is like I am sending some data as parameters to call and some in payload.after getting 302 it gets redirected.But the issue is once it gets redirected,POST call gets converted to GET call and payload is lost.As a result I am unable to get desired search result.Is there anything related to config that I might be missing??

Comment: Sounds like standard behavior. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: But same thing has worked in POSTMAN

Comment: @swapna if you like postman so much, please use it instead :P

Comment: This is not the case that I like postman.Thing is I am wondering that same request was working in postman but not in karate so did I miss anything related to cofig.I really liked karate framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the correct behavior. Sounds like you need to disable automatic re-directs for this test, see [`configure`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure). You can do:

```
* configure followRedirects = false
```

And then get the redirect location manually as follows:

```
* def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
```

Refer to this test for an example: [`redirect.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/redirect/redirect.feature)