# Karate only seems to support the password flow are there any examples of the auth code flow or better still auth code with pkce

Tags: karate, pkce

The only example for oauth is https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature

which is for the password flow are their any examples for the auth code flow or better still auth code with pkce?

Answer (score 0):

I feel such examples are not needed, because Karate is simple - you can make HTTP calls including URL-encoded forms and use the responses for future calls.

So it completely depends on your environment and the specific auth flow.

Do look at the other examples - and here are a couple of answers that may give you ideas:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019538/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475

Also, no one has contributed such an example. Perhaps you can once you figure it out :)

Comment: I dont think there is anything to figure out, either karate copes with redirects or it doesnt.

Comment: @mcrobbj you never mentioned redirects, so maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214630/143475 - if not please assume that karate is not the tool for you, so look for another one. or contribute code, it is open source.